# Displaying the print where there is no error

Tags: python-3.x

```
if password:
    if blank > 0:
        errorcount += 1
    if letter > 0:
       errorcount += 1
    if upper < 1:
        errorcount += 1
    if lower < 1:
        errorcount += 1
    if numbdig < 2:
        errorcount += 1
    if passwords < minimum:
        errorcount += 1
    print(password, 'is not valid', errorcount, 'errors!')
else:
    print(password, 'is valid!')
```

When there is 0 error the else should print but instead the not valid prints instead.

Comment: Please share what you are passing in `password`.

Comment: 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase, 6 digits. no space and the first character in the password is a letter.

Comment: @Noodlez did below solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct because the case of no error means outer `if` block i.e. 
`if password` will be true, so your `else` will not be executed.

Inside `if password`, there is a print statement which is getting printed.

What you can do is, put a check on your `errorcount` variable & print accordingly:

```
if errorcount >= 1:
    print(password, 'is not valid', errorcount, 'errors!')
else:
    print(password, 'is valid!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do a check for `errorcount` after it has been calculated

```
if password:
    if blank > 0:
        errorcount += 1
    if letter > 0:
        errorcount += 1
    if upper < 1:
        errorcount += 1
    if lower < 1:
        errorcount += 1
    if numbdig < 2:
        errorcount += 1
    if passwords < minimum:
        errorcount += 1

    if errorcount > 0: #check here
        print(password, 'is not valid', errorcount, 'errors!')
    else: #no error
        print(password, 'is valid!')
else: #password is null or false
    print(password, 'is null!')
```